# Send data from a model to a delegate

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `tableView` that has a column that is using a `comboBox`. I need to fill the `comboBox` using the delegate class with the data from the model class. I was using signals and slots for this task but I know there is a method using `data`.

This is how i create and fill the `comboBox`. I need to get the file row directly from the model class without already storing it in the delegate.

```
QWidget *CDelegate :: createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */, const QModelIndex & index) const
{

 if(index.column() == COL_ComboBox)
    {
        QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);

        for(int i=0; i<file.at(index.row()).size(); i++)
           editor -> addItem(file.at(index.row()).at(i))

        return editor;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: What is "file"? And how it was filled?

Comment: file is a vector of vectors of strings. It stores every comboBox in the column and the date that is stored in them. I made this as a temporary solution until i figure it out how the system of delegate and model can by apply on it.

Comment: I need a solution to send all the data of a comboBox at once. Does not matter how this data is stored.

Comment: Vector of vectors of strings contains data from model of tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to fill `QComboBox` with data from model of your `QTableView`. As you see, `const QModelIndex & index` parameter in `createEditor` function provides you access to this model. Look for method [model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#model) of `QModelIndex` class. Thats' why, your `createEditor` function may be like this:

```
QWidget *CDelegate :: createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &/* option */, const QModelIndex & index) const
{

 if(index.column() == COL_ComboBox)
    {
        QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);

        const QAbstractItemModel *model = index.model();

        while(/*condition*/)
        {
            // take data from model
            // QVariant dt = model->data(...);

            // fill editor with data from dt
            // editor->addItem(...)
        }

        return editor;
    }
...
}
```